# Dynamically scaling set of coordinates in a dictonary

Tags: python, dictionary

This is the dictionary I am trying to get into a scaling/dynamic dictionary.

```
koordinatstring = {
    CoordinateTitle:
    {
        PositionTitle:
        {
            "X": Xvalue,
            "Y": Yvalue
        },
        PositionTitle:
        {
            "X": Xvalue,
            "Y": Yvalue
        },
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a loop that will let me create exactly as many sets of coordinates that will look like this:

```
PositionTitle:
{
     "X": Xvalue,
     "Y": Yvalue
},
```

Where `PositionTitle` and `"X": Xvalue` and finally `"Y": Yvalue` are variables I get from other sources.

And at the end I dump all this as a Json.

To Clarify.

I am looking to iterate through a loop that when I tell it too either through a set of hotkeys, like ctrl-4 or E the loop will terminate and continue to on with other code I might have.

But while the loop runs, it should be able to create anything from

```
koordinatstring = {
    CoordinateTitle:
    {
        PositionTitle:
        {
            "X": Xvalue,
            "Y": Yvalue
        },
    }
}
```

as a dictonary to this:

```
koordinatstring = {
    CoordinateTitle:
    {
        PositionTitle:
        {
            "X": Xvalue,
            "Y": Yvalue
        },
        PositionTitle:
        {
            "X": Xvalue,
            "Y": Yvalue
        },
        PositionTitle:
        {
        "X": Xvalue,
        "Y": Yvalue
        },
        PositionTitle:
        {
        "X": Xvalue,
        "Y": Yvalue
        },
    }
}
```

I believe you would call this scale ability or something similar when it comes to programming.

Comment: Do you mean you need the list of all the `PositionTitle` objects? Else please explain what you mean by *"create a loop that will let me create exactly as many sets of coordinates"*

Comment: Perhaps I used the wrong language here. I want to dynamically be able to set the amount of loops of the (PosistionTitle:) and it's content goes through. So say, I need to create a set of 8 variables for this dictonary, I am looking to create a loop that will let my fill up the (CoordinateTitle:) level with 8 sets of (PosistionTitle:) variables. Preferably by letting me execute a command or click a button that lets my exit the loop. (This last part I can add by myself.)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple),

```
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')

pt1 = Point(2.0, 3.0)
```